# How to copy settings from previous using command line

Tags: scripting, command-line

When i downloaded the latest version of blender, this option show up in splash screen "Copy settings from previous".

So how to do it in command line? because I have 50 pc and I want to simplify the process using ssh and run blender from command line.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the tooltips, Mas Aditia, and you'll see that it's [`wm.copy_prev_settings`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.ops.wm.html#bpy.ops.wm.copy_prev_settings). For remote deployment, it might also be necessary to [`quit_blender`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.ops.wm.html#bpy.ops.wm.quit_blender) right after executing the script. So the simplest script would be:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.wm.copy_prev_settings()
bpy.ops.wm.quit_blender()
```

Save it as to a script file with any name, and execute Blender while running the script:

```
blender -P <script_name>.py
```

As the operator copies the config folder right away, nothing else needs to be done.

Comment: I've added -b in the syntax above to make it run in background

Comment: Uh, yeah, I forgot about `-b` switch. Great then, 'cause I think its usage makes `quit_blender` unnecessary :)